# C-Band in Optical Fiber Communication

Tags: frequency, wave, optical-fibre

I've read that the C-Band used in optical communication ranges from 1530 – 1565 nm.  Since one nanometer corresponds to 0.000000000299792458 GHZ, this is far less than 1 GHz. However, the C-Band is divided into multiple 50 GHz channels. How can this be the case, if it's range isn't even 1 GHz?

I guess I just messed things up when converting the units but I cannot figure out what?!

Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Comment: I have not the slightest idea how you came up with that number of GHz, so you might want to tell how you arrived at it so we can point out the flaw (hint: the wavelength you gave corresponds to around 200THz)

Comment: What value were you using for the speed of light? In what system of units?

Comment: @BrianDrummond: I suspect megasmoots per fortnight

Comment: 1 nanometer is 10 Angstroms, one 800th of the wavelength of red light. There is plenty of bandwidth to handle multiple channels of 50GHz.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a simple arithmetic error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1530 nm corresponds to \$\frac{c}{\lambda}=\$ 196.1 THz; 1565 nm corresponds to 191.7 THz. Therefore the bandwidth spanned by the C band is about 4.4 THz, which is much more than 1 GHz, not less than 1 GHz.

Comment: http://www.easyunitconversion.com/en/frequency/wavelength-in-nanometers-to-gigahertz

it says that 35 nm correspond to  1.1675×10^{-25} GHz.  whatever^^

Comment: where did you find the formula to get the THz values? :)

Comment: @aymi, it's an old physics joke:
Q: What's nu?
A: Cee over lambda.

Comment: Also, delete that link from your bookmarks. It looks like it's simply broken.

Comment: @aymi Indeed it does say that. That's because it's wrong.